# Postfix and GMail

Tags: server, 18.04, email, postfix, gmail

I have set up postfix on a server that it forwards root mail to my Gmail. I have a problem with postfix.

When mail from `root@mydomain` come to Gmail it goes to Inbox Folder and Send Folder. The Send folder keeps the same message. I explain. When I delete the message in Sent folder it deletes in Inbox folder too. When I delete the message in Inbox folder it deletes in Sent folder too.

I have the message:

```
From: myemail@gmail.com
To: root@mydomain
Bcc: myemail@gmail.com
```

Here is my postfix conf:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_loglevel=1
smtp_tls_security_level=encrypt
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_un$
myhostname = mydomain
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = $myhostname, mydomain, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
recipient_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_bcc
```

Why does it happen? Don't the message try to go out to the internet and find the `mydomain` on the internet?

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer to your question.  It may or may not be of any use to you.  If you are only sending admin mail to yourself, Mailgun offers a free mail forwarding service for that purpose.  Then you just override your `sendmail` with a script file to send using the Mailgun API.

Comment: @CraigHicks Thanks a log for your trying to help me. I setup own IMAP server and so I decided this question.